# Restore deleted files after Windows HDD repair

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

On an HDD Windows 10 wanted to check and repair the files. After the Check and Repair some files are gone. I do have Linux and I hoped Linux can just read them. I found the recycle bin on the HDD, however these missing files weren't in there.
Do you have any suggestion how to restore these files?
Kind regards

Comment: You will need to restore them from backup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 0):

So: The solution for me was:
I found the LOST directory. There all my data were. However not in the correct file format. On Linux it was no problem to open these (as Linux doesn't care about the ending).

PDFs however aren't restored 100% correct. Just changing the ending to .pdf does the thing for Linux. However the friend of mine using Adobe Reader cannot open these (Opening the PDFs with a Browser like Edge seems to work).
So For PDFs I need to print them to pdf. This seems to work.